# Is there an file explorer for windows that lets me open multiple tabs programmatically

Tags: explorer

I'm writing an application that helps us manage multiple computers. It has a menu to open the certain bookmarked folders on several computers(using the hidden c$/d$/e$/... drives) for comparison. Currently I just open a bunch of explorer windows but I thought it would be nicer to have the option to open them in tabs.

(regular file explorer not norton commander style)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a tab control. Then you create a new tab and load it with the explorer.
There are tabbed file explorers like XYplorer, but I don't know if it will be useful to you.

You can also add tabs to windows explorer: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/28997/add-tabbed-browsing-to-explorer-in-windows-7/